# Assigning one of many values to object's property

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication

I want to parse a firebase auth credentials object which is differently formatted for various sign in methods.

For example for password sign up the data I want are in **credentials** directly, but for facebook or google login the data I want are in **credentials.user**

So I have this function going:

```
parseCredentials(credentials: any): User {
    const parsedCredentials: User = {
      displayName: credentials.displayName || credentials.user.displayName,
      email: credentials.email || credentials.user.email,
      emailVerified: credentials.emailVerified || credentials.user.emailVerified,
      uid: credentials.uid || credentials.user.uid
    };
    return parsedCredentials;
  }
```

As you can see I use the function to return a new User object based on the credentials passed to the fn, because I don't need unnecessary information in the User object.

The problem is when I sing up with email-password I get error: **credentials.user is undefined**

I think is something wrong with the || operators. It seems that credentials.user is undefined (because the user property does not exist on credentials object when signing up with email-password).

But thats why I used the || operator. Struggling with this for a while but I can't figure out. Hope you can give some help. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: "credentials.user is undefined" is the error.

Comment: And are you sure that happens in a scenario where `credentials.displayName` is in fact defined?

Comment: Oh crap how did you know? I missed that one. When signing up with email-password the displayName property is null. Thanks @bugs

Comment: Well, because if `credentials.displayName` were defined, `credentials.user.displayName` wouldn't even be evalauted

Comment: If you post an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

In each case, what's on the right-hand side of the `||` is not evaluated if what's on the left is not `undefined`.

Most likely the error is due to `credentials.displayName` being `undefined`, which means that the program will try to evaluate `credentials.user.displayName`.